# web2py: Use divs in generated radiobutton instead of table

Tags: web2py

I have a table:

```
db.define_table('table1',
    Field('name', 'string', length=16, required=True, unique=True),
    Field('shape', 'string', length=12, default='star', widget=SQLFORM.widgets.radio.widget, requires=IS_IN_SET(shapes)))
```

I use this SQLFORM to generate the form:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.table1, formstyle='divs')
```

I have the main form using divs, but the radio buttons, still use tables, which is really the one I want in divs. How can can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to create a custom widget (see http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Widgets). For example:

```
def div_radio_widget(field, value, **attributes):
    table=SQLFORM.widgets.radio.widget(field, value, **attributes)
    return DIV(
        *[SPAN(td.element('input'), LABEL(td.components[1]))
          for td in table.elements('td')],
        **table.attributes)
```

The above widget first creates a table using the built-in radio button widget and then pulls out the input elements and labels from the TD's and puts everything in a DIV.

In your table definition, just replace:

```
widget=SQLFORM.widget.radio.widget
```

with:

```
widget=div_radio_widget
```